# Density plot of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, matlab-figure, density-plot

I have a `100x200` matrix and I would like to show this matrix as a density plot. Here is a `8x10` sample.

```
X = [104 122 138 159 149 167 184 164 190 158; ...
     54  42  55  55  63  75  72  73  66  76; ...
     15  22  28  21  23  28  32  47  32  40; ...
     18  12  20  22  28  17  30  17  22  18; ...
     10  7   14  10  14  11  14  20  16  10; ...
     5   6   3   3   6   12  6   2   8   9; ...
     4   8   9   2   5   3   3   12  7   7; ...
     6   6   2   3   10  1   9   8   11  8]
```

I have tried to use functions like `bar3`, `surf`, `hist` and so on but they don't have the end result I am after.

I would also like to represent the y axis on the new successful plot to be on a log axis. So similar to having `semilogy(x,y,'rx')` for example.

Are there any other methods I could use?

[image]

Comment: Do you want a flat surface (smoothed) where the upper part is dark red, and the lower part is blue, (or something similar), or a 3D-plot with the high numbers as peaks (smoothed), a 3D bar plot (not smoothed), or something else?

Comment: So a red colour would reflect a higher number in the matrix. A blue colour would represent a low number. So I am after a plot where the colours range from blue-red depending on the number in the matrix.

Comment: I am not really sure what the result should be. Do you need something like `imagesc(X)`? Or maybe could you upload a small sketch?

Comment: I will attempt a sketch!

Comment: Do you want it "smoothed", or like bars?

Comment: The log scale on the y axis can be achieved using `set(gca,'YScale','log')`, but you will most likely want the z axis to be a log scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about "surf" it like a spectrogram?

```
XX = log([104 122 138 159 149 167 184 164 190 158; 
          54  42  55  55  63  75  72  73  66  76; 
          15  22  28  21  23  28  32  47  32  40; 
          18  12  20  22  28  17  30  17  22  18; 
          10  7   14  10  14  11  14  20  16  10; 
           5   6   3   3   6   12  6   2   8   9; 
           4   8   9   2   5   3   3   12  7   7; 
           6   6   2   3   10  1   9   8   11  8]

figure
surf(XX, 'edgecolor', 'none'); view(0,90); axis tight;
xlabel ('x')
ylabel ('y')
```

[image]

NOTE:The first row represent the first row (104,122,138...)
     and row 8 represent row 8 (6,7,2....) 
Dark red = high value
light blue = low value

Comment: What do you mean by log the y-axis? Do you mean log the z-axis? I did log(X) already, the x and y axis now represent the index of your matrix X, while the colours (z-axis) represent the log of your values in X

Comment: Yeah I rather stupidly skim read the matrix on your answer. Brilliant, merci

Answer (score 4):

Matlab also provides a heatmap function.

```
>> X = [104 122 138 159 149 167 184 164 190 158; ...
     54  42  55  55  63  75  72  73  66  76; ...
     15  22  28  21  23  28  32  47  32  40; ...
     18  12  20  22  28  17  30  17  22  18; ...
     10  7   14  10  14  11  14  20  16  10; ...
     5   6   3   3   6   12  6   2   8   9; ...
     4   8   9   2   5   3   3   12  7   7; ...
     6   6   2   3   10  1   9   8   11  8];
>> heatmap(X)

ans = 

  HeatmapChart with properties:

    ColorData: [8×10 double]

  Show all properties
```

The following plot appears:
[image: Heatmap of the matrix X]